# How to hide a div after regular scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am a beginner and learning by myself, by taking help of stack-overflow and other online tutorials.

Well, I tried a lot of scripts, seems not a single one worked for me except this one. However all of my trials are working in localhost but post production they don't, seems some conflict.

Here are the working codes

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
  var target = document.getElementsByClassName('cta-bg');
  if(window.pageYOffset > 500){
   target[0].style.display = "block"; 
  }
  else if(window.pageYOffset < 500){
    target[0].style.display = "none";
  }
},false);
```

```css
.cta-bg{
padding:2em;
background-color: #000;
position: sticky;
bottom: 10%;
top: 40%;
width: 70%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-bg">some content here</div>
```

I want to show my div between the scroll of 500-1500 only, I tried

```
window.pageYOffset < 500 && window.pageYOffset > 1500
```

but it's not working for me, please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried `window.pageYOffset > 500 && window.pageYOffset < 1500` and it's working fine.

Also set `display: none;` for the `div` to hide it by default.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var target = document.getElementsByClassName('cta-bg');
  console.log(window.pageYOffset);
  if (window.pageYOffset > 500 && window.pageYOffset < 1500) {
    target[0].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    target[0].style.display = "none";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}
.cta-bg {
  display: none;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #000;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 10%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-bg">some content here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir :) It's working fine now, I am having one question- Can we set the scroll range 500- 1500 dynamically so that it will appear dynamically as per the content (for less content and more content both), I want to show CTA after 20% scroll of header and before 20% scroll of footer in sidebar. Thanks a lot :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope the solution below helps:

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'scroll',
  function (e) {
    var target = document.getElementsByClassName("cta-bg")[0];
    if (window.scrollY > 500 && window.scrollY < 1500) {
      target.innerText = window.scrollY;
      target.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
      target.style.display = "none";
    }
  },
);
```

```css
.filler {
  padding-bottom: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cta-bg {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #000;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 10%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="cta-bg">some content here</div>
<div class="filler"></div>
```